# How to Convert Hours, minutes and seconds (HH:mm:ss) to minutes and seconds (mm:ss) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have 2hrs, 47minutes and 10 second (02:47:10) which is in hh:mm:ss format as a value in Time column. I would like to convert it to minutes and seconds only (mm:ss).
Hence the result should be 167minutes and 10 secs in sql.
I have tried using the code

```
SELECT cast(substring('02:47:10',1,2) AS int)*60+
       cast(substring('02:47:10',4,2) AS int)+ 
       cast(substring('02:47:10',7,2) AS int)/60.0 AS minutes
```

The result was 167.166666.

My desired output should be 167:10 (mm:ss) format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a lighter approach with less string manipulation

**Example**

```
Declare @T time = '02:47:10'

Select concat(datediff(MINUTE,0,@T),':',datepart(second,@T))
```

**Results**

```
167:10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the hours by 60, and then add it to the minutes. Then reformat as a time like value:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT((DATEPART(HOUR,'02:47:10')* 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE,'02:47:10'),':',DATEPART(SECOND,'02:47:10'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Amended your expession

```
SELECT cast (cast(substring('02:47:10',1,2) AS int) * 60 +
             cast(substring('02:47:10',4,2) AS int) as varchar(10)) + ':' +
       substring('02:47:10',7,2) AS minutes
```